# Jackson ObjectMapper convert list to byte array with new line separator

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to convert a list of entities to a specific format:

```
    /* this method converts list of dto to
    *       [
    *         {"field1": "a"},
    *         {"field1": "b"},
    *         {"field1": "c"}
    *       ]
    * 
    * */ 
    public byte[] transform1(MyDto dto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return dto.getEntities() == null ||
        dto.getEntities().isEmpty() ? new byte[]{} : new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(dto.getEntities());
    }

    /*
    My goal is to convert list to following shape (as bytes):
    * 
    *         {"field1": "a"}
    *         {"field1": "b"}
    *         {"field1": "c"}
    *
    *          Note: there are no [] braces, objects separated by \n
     */
    public byte[] transform2(MyDto dto) throws IOException {
        if (dto.getEntities() == null || dto.getEntities().isEmpty()){
            return new byte[]{};
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try (SequenceWriter seq = mapper.writer().withRootValueSeparator("\n").writeValues(baos)) {
            for (Integer entity : dto.getEntities()) {
                seq.write(entity);
            }
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

The problem with `transform2` is that it leads to `OutOfMemoryError`. Does Jackson have some standard way to achieve the same result as transform2 but in a more efficient way? Or do I need to implement my own method? Any suggestions?

Comment: Jackson isn't the problem. The problem is that you are writing to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which will keep everything as a `byte[]` in memory. If you write to some other stream, like a file or socket, you should be fine.

Comment: @Jorn but why if I'm testing with the same amount of data method 1 is working fine, but method 2 is not?

Comment: Maybe it decides to enlarge the `byte[]` at a different time, and the second method happens to need more memory for the copy? This is machine-dependent, so only you can really answer that question.

Comment: @Jorn ok, if we don't consider `OutOfMemoryError` how can I achieve the same result (I mean data structure) using Jackson?